# capturar variable en um trigger mysql

Tags: sql, mysqli

Buenas noches de verdad gracias por su tiempo, les cuento
 Tengo una tabla gastos con varios campos como idgasto,proveedor,cliente,total y una mas detalle_gasto que tiene por campos idgasto,idproducto hasta hay todo bien,pero la aplicación es web y para algunos controles de información, estoy usando trigger entonces, decidí crear una tabla temporal donde tiene los mismo campos que detalle_gasto excepto idgasto para que el trigger clone los datos de allí a detalle_gasto after insert de gasto. El problema es como le digo al trigger que clone los datos y que coloque el id correspondiente en el campo idgasto..
.espero haber sido claro y nuevamente gracias

Comment: Buenas, por favor revisa [ask] y [mcve] para que te podamos ayudar mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías hacerlo sería la siguiente:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER CopiarGastos AFTER INSERT ON gastos
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN  
    INSERT INTO tabla_gastos_copia select * from tabla_gastos where idgasto = NEW.idgasto;
END;//
DELIMITER ;
```

Básicamente lo que hace es que después de insertar en la **tabla tabla_gastos**, por cada fila insertada en la tabla **tabla_gastos** (que será 1) te inserta en la tabla **tabla_gastos_copia** el mismo registro.

*EDIT: no es obligatorio que la tabla de copia tenga NO tenga id autoincremental, pero desde mi punto de vista para este caso no lo pondría por si en algún momento haces reordenación de id's y demás al borrar campos, podría dar conflictos.*

Espero haber sido de ayuda, saludos!!

Comment: Buenas noches, tu línea de código me ayudo mucho pero surge que el gasto es uno correcto, hay todo bien pero los detallesdel gastos son varios y antes de insertar el detalle tengo que tener el id del gasto,puede que sea uno pero también puede ser 10 filas con el mismo id y el 'where' del 'select' no reconoce la columna si escribo 'id.detalle_gasto', debería ser algo como 'where id.detalle_gasto=new.id.gasto' como lo termino espero puedas ayudar y gracias  por tu tiempo

Comment: Buenas, no tenía acceso a internet este finde. A ver si he comprendido bien, quieres ingresar un gasto desde un aplicativo en la base de datos y quieres que cuando se inserte se haga una copia de ese gasto en otra tabla (esto es lo que hace el código de arriba). Ahora quieres que al insertar un gasto se inserten los detalles (que pueden ser varias líneas de detalle) en la tabla de detalles_gasto, no?

Comment: correcto, excepto la copia de gasto, 3 tablas gastos,detalle_gastos una relacionada de otra y  detalle_gasto que no esta relacionada a nada solo tiene los mismos campos que detalle_gasto esto es debido a que la aplicacion es web y para evitarme problemas con el grid entonces decidi almacenar primero los detalles del gastos y al boton guardar llama un modal que tiene los campos del gasto, al guardar el gasto se debe relacionar todo lo anterior

Comment: Pero el detalle del gasto pueden ser varias líneas diferentes, no? Ejemplo: 1 gasto de 500€, 1er detalle (300€ concepto seguro), 2ndo detalle (200€ concepto ropa). Si esto es así, creo que habría que realizarlo desde la aplicación, diciéndole qué cosa vas a almacenar en cada tabla, me explico? (porque ya no estaríamos hablando de una copia). Saludos!!

Comment: Correcto, yo entiendo pasa que como es web tengo problemas con el grid en jquery y pensé en esta tabla temporal, no lo veas como copia de la tabla, por que la tabla temporal solo tendrá los detalles mientras se guarda el gasto una vez el gasto se guarde y los datos se clonen de esta tabla temporal serán borrados los datos para un muevo imgreso

Comment: A eso me refería, deberías realizar esa lógica en la aplicación, no en base de datos, me explico, tienes un gasto y una serie de detalles, guardas el gasto en la base de datos y si te devuelve todo correcto (tb te devolverá el id, pues guardas los detalles enlazados a ese id). Sinceramente creo que es la mejor manera y como mejor aprenderás también. Te recomendaría que abrieses otra pregunta con el código que usas para guardar y lo que pretendes hacer para que te podamos ayudar. (Si aún así deseas hacerlo como dices, será indispensable ver el código que utilizas en el servidor para guardar) :)

Comment: Ya lo habia hecho, aquí esta el link de la pregunta. Lo que pueda resolver primero y por cierto muchas gracias .  https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/86139/como-obtener-el-id-de-una-fila-en-cgridview