# como obtener el id de una fila en CgridView

Tags: php, yii, popup

buenas noches estoy tratando de capturar el id de una fila desde un CgridView con una ventana emergente, y colocarlo en una caja de texto desde donde esta siendo llamado pero me trae valor `undefined` en  yiiframework espero puedan ayudarme, les dejo el codigo usado

funcion que llama a la ventana donde se encuentra el CgridView

```
 <script >
 function buscarArticulo() {
 window.open("../articulo/catInventario", "popupId", "location=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no, menubar=no,width=500,height=500"); 
 }
 </script>
```

esta es la funcion en la ventana emergente:

```
<script language="javascript">
function cerrar(idarticulo) {
window.opener.document.getElementById('idarticulo').value = <?php echo $model->idarticulo; //the new id ?> 
window.close();
}
</script>
```

este es el widget del CgridView

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'catInventario-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter'=>$model,
    'columns'=>array(
        'idarticulo',
        'codigo',
        'nombre',
        'descripcion',
        'imagen',
        'uso_interno',
        /*
        'idcategoria',
        'idpresentacion',
        'cod_impuesto',
        */
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{elegir}',
            'buttons'=>array(
                'elegir'=>array(
                    'click'=>'cerrar',
                    ),

                ),

        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

este es el modelo, donde se encuentra el searh para la busqueda completa

```
public function search()
{


    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('idarticulo',$this->idarticulo);
    $criteria->compare('codigo',$this->codigo,true);
    $criteria->compare('nombre',$this->nombre,true);
    $criteria->compare('descripcion',$this->descripcion,true);
    $criteria->compare('imagen',$this->imagen,true);
    $criteria->compare('uso_interno',$this->uso_interno,true);
    $criteria->compare('idcategoria',$this->idcategoria);
    $criteria->compare('idpresentacion',$this->idpresentacion);
    $criteria->compare('cod_impuesto',$this->cod_impuesto,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

y esta es la funcion del controlador:

```
public function actionCatInventario()
{
    $model=new Articulo('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Articulo']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Articulo'];

    $this->render('catInventario',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

como se dan cuenta, es para un formulario de gastos web y para este sentido solo necesito el idarticulo, espero haber sido claro y puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Por qué lo abres en una ventana nueva y no mejor en un cuadro modal? (así tendrías los elementos en la misma página) Algunos navegadores dan problemas con las ventanas emergentes)

Comment: Me trae el ultimo id, si tengo 20 row y selecciono el 1ero se trae el 20. Pensé que así tendrá mas libertad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solucione, gracias a una respuesta en el foro en ingles aca el link para el que lo necesite
[respuesta a esta misma pregunta en el foro de ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45136074/get-the-value-of-a-value-in-the-widgets-cgridview)